# How to wait properly for Storage event?

Tags: javascript, browser

I need a secure way to store authentication token, but I want to let the users use the app on multiple tabs without reauthenticate every time. So I need `sessionStorage`'s impersistence, with `localStorage`'s multi-tab accessibility. That's why I'm implementing [browser cross-tab communication with Storage events](https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/).

The concept is, on startup the app writes some data to `localStorage`, which fires a [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) on every tab (with the same domain). In the event's callback, other instances can send back data in another StorageEvent's payload. So the new instance can collect data, like an authentication token.

The problem is, the `addEventListener` callback is asynchronous, and if there are no other tabs, nothing will be called, so it's not trivial to decide, when should my app render the login form instead of the content. (My app's initial render is synchronous, but in the most cases the event arrives before the auth logic.)

I tried `setImmediate`, which increased the number of proper behaviours, but there are some cases, when the callback still fires too late.

How could I wait for such an async event properly?

Comment: Instead of using setImmediate, use setInterval to check to see if the StorageEvent has fired.  When the StorageEvent fires, have it set a global variable which is accessible from anywhere in the current tab.  Then when this variable is set, the function defined in the setInterval call should then stop checking and call whatever code that you need to run from that point on.